# Como colocar 2 parametros al input tag cuando se carga la pagina

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap

Estoy utilizando el plugin **Bootstrap Tags Input**, y generando una tabla dinamica con php que la cargo a traves de jquery con el metodo Load. Esta tabla tiene inputs en donde muestro con tags lo que hay guardado alli, para ello lo hago asi:

```
<input type='text' value='prueba, otra prueba' data-role='tagsinput'/>
```

y en javascript:

```
jQuery('input').tagsinput('refresh');
```

El problema es que la etiqueta que se carga solo tiene 1 parametro que es el nombre de la etiqueta y yo necesito que tenga tambien el ID. ¿Como puedo hacer eso?. En la documentacion del plugin dice asi:

```
$('input').tagsinput('add', { id: 1, text: 'some tag' });
```

Pero no puedo hacerlo asi porque la tabla se genera en un archivo externo que cargo, como dije, con el metodo Load de Jquery. Espero haberme podido explicar y desde ya gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En realidad no he usado Bootstrap Tags Input, pero según la [documentación](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/), tendrías que inicializar el input de a siguiente manera

```
 $('.input').tagsinput({
      allowDuplicates: false,
        itemValue: 'id',  // Será usado para el id
        itemText: 'label' // Será usado para el texto
    });
```

Después, podrías hacer lo que pretendes

```
$('input').tagsinput('add', { id: '0', label: 'EjemploTexto' });
```

Saludos